# Dependable dropdown and getValues() 2D array

Tags: google-apps-script, drop-down-menu, google-sheets

I am building dependable (filtered) dropdown in google sheet, where value in the one dropdown list depends on the choice of another. Although being a releatively simple arrangement, I came across the problem with [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
which returns 2D array.

There is the following set up:

1. Two sheets, one **Activity** and another **$SheetData**.
2. Column E of the **Activity** contains dropdowns, which when selected, should provide appropriate choice in the column G.
3. The data for Column E is sourced from sheet **$SheetData** (E1:K1);
4. The data for Column G is sourced from sheet **$SheetData** from each of the respective columns (E1 = SIRE: SIRE1, SIRE2 etc);
5. When SIRE is selected in Col E of **Activity**, I need the data in column G to be from E2:E of the **$SheetData**
   Here is my code:

```
function dependableDropdown() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activity = ss.getSheetByName("Activity");
  var sheetData = ss.getSheetByName("$SheetData");
  var activeCell = activity.getActiveCell();

  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 5 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

    var inspectionTypes = sheetData.getRange(1, 5, 1, 7).getValues();    

    var selectedValue = activeCell.getValue();
    var inspectionTypesIndex = inspectionTypes[0].indexOf(selectedValue) + 1;

    var validationRange = sheetData.getRange(2, inspectionTypesIndex, sheetData.getLastRow());

    var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
    activeCell.offset(0, 2).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  };
};
```

Value returned by `inspectionTypesIndex` seems to be correct (SIRE = 1, OVID = 2 etc), but when I select data in Col E, I get the wrong data fed into the column G.

Apprecaite your help.
Thank you,

---

Corresponding screens:

***Activity sheet***
[image: Activity sheet]

***$SheetData***
[image: Data sheet]

Comment: How do you trigger the above function `dependableDropdown()`? Or do you run it manually as preliminary test?

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин there is onEdit() down below where  dependableDropdown() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `inspectionTypesIndex` as written (SIRE = 1, OVID = 2 etc), and you have options columns: E, F, G, ... , then you should reference `validationRange` in the following way:

```
var validationRange = sheetData.getRange(2, inspectionTypesIndex + 4, sheetData.getLastRow());
```

because E column is 5-th, but "SIRE" index is equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you! Of course, how could I missed that apparent bloomer!